# JQuery Script Load Timing

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a button that sets off a jquery script is there a way to make sure the button is inactive until the script completes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Somewhere at the beginning of your script (probably on the button's click event), set the button's disabled attribute to true:

```
$("#mybutton").attr("disabled", true);
```

Then, when complete, remove that attribute:

```
$("#mybutton").removeAttr("disabled");
```

EDIT:

If you want to get (slightly) fancy, change the text of the button while you're doing the work.  If it's an image button, you can change the src to a friendly "please wait" message.  Here's an example of the button text version:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
  var origVal = $(this).attr("value");

  $(this).attr("value", "Please wait...");
  $(this).attr("disabled", true);

  //Do your processing.

  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
  $(this).attr("value", origVal);
});
```

Answer (score 37):

This is one area where I like to extend jQuery:

```
$.fn.disable = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (typeof this.disabled != "undefined") this.disabled = true;
    });
}

$.fn.enable = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (typeof this.disabled != "undefined") this.disabled = false;
    });
}
```

and then you can do:

```
$("#button").disable();
$("#button").enable();
```

I find myself disabling/enabling controls a lot.

Comment: I prefer this solution. You could easily enhance the function to change the text, too.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks cletus for your function. I have used your function and created my own to toggle disabled elements.

```
$.fn.toggleDisable = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (typeof this.disabled != "undefined"){
                if(this.disabled){
                    this.disabled = false;
                }else{
                    this.disabled = true;
                }
        }
    });
}
```