# How to set focus on an div from a button click through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a aspx page where in I have made a form. There is a help button on this form.When I click on the help button I have created html code in Javascript.

```
    function help_For_admin()
{

var Message_Help = '<p><b>Admin Page Description</b></p>'


 document.getElementById("help").innerHTML =Message_Help ; 
 document.getElementById("Div_Admin").style.display = "";
   }
```

Now when I click on the help button I want the div Div_admin to get focus and the remaining elements of the aspx page to be disabled and when I close the div window the aspx page to get focus.How can I do this.I would like an answer without the use of jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to disable all div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content)

Similar to what your trying to do with disabling, instead of a checkbox...

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery blockUI to easily to disable any portion of the page.
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

Answer (score 0):

Place any server side  control bellow the `div` and write the `button.fous()` in the page load or other event. Or with javascript using the `focus()` function, for example

```
document.getElementById('Div id').focus();
```