# disable all form elements inside div

Tags: jquery, forms, html, field

is there a way to disable all fields (textarea/textfield/option/input/checkbox/submit etc) in a form by telling only the parent div name in jquery/javascript?

Comment: Note that by doing this you cause the values of those elements to "disappear" when submitting the form - to preserve the value make them `readOnly`, not disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable all div content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content)

Comment: An Idea could be hide/show a div in front of the controls it allows/prevents from be clicked, plus style disabled controls with css.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Try using the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector, along with a parent selector:

```
$("#parent-selector :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: can i use this to set all inputs inside div to value 0?

Comment: I want to disable <a> also... My <a> has onclick too

Comment: Citing [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/): _Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :input cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :input to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":input")._

Comment: @acme: Agree 100% but the question doesn't give any hints as to what selector I could possibly filter on. The only information I was given was that the user must be able to do it with a *parent `div` name* and that's it. If given more information I could have come up with a more efficient solution.

Comment: You're right - I just wanted to mention this for the sake of completeness. Though I guess the performance boost comes only into play with lots of form fields.

Comment: if you want to disable all the elements, not only inputs but some custom buttons, use children(): $('#your-form').children().prop('disabled', true);

Comment: Use .prop() instead of .attr() (above jquery 1.6)

Comment: @acme i tried $("#my_frm").filter(":input").prop('disabled', true); but it's not working (however code in this answer works)...any ideas why?

Comment: input not able to handle select (dropdown), need to have one more selector for select:  $("#parent-selector :input, #parent-selector select").attr("disabled", true);

Comment: @Andrew: which jQuery version do you use?

Comment: @acme jquery-1.12.4.min.js and if I remember correctly, it was regarding selection dropdowns

Answer (score 165):

```
$('#mydiv').find('input, textarea, button, select').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: it should be ('input, textarea, button') all selectors should be quoted with one set of quotes. http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ Doing it your way you are sending multiple arguments.

Comment: This will only find you inputs, ignoring textareas and buttons. The :input selector is the way to go, but if you wanted to list them explicitly, you would need to use `$('#mydiv').find('input, textarea, button')`.

Comment: ...or just $('#your-form').children().prop('disabled', true);

Comment: @walv  your code **only** works if all the form elements are a single descendent of the form. Find() finds all of the elements in the list regardless of descendent level.  
This line of code is correct other than using the prop instead of  attr for new jquery versions.

Answer (score 33):

For jquery 1.6+, use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/),

```
$("#parent-selector :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

or

```
$("#parent-selector :input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: you are right but some time prop work and some time not work,specially in cause of checkbox and radiobutton

Comment: i realize that this is an old thread, but this kicks up some errors when using typescript

Answer (score 9):

Simply this line of code will disable all input elements

```
$('#yourdiv *').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: best answer from my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#chkDisableEnableElements').change(function () {
            if ($('#chkDisableEnableElements').is(':checked')) {
                enableElements($('#divDifferentElements').children());
            }
            else {
                disableElements($('#divDifferentElements').children());
            }
        });
    });

    function disableElements(el) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            el[i].disabled = true;

            disableElements(el[i].children);
        }
    }

    function enableElements(el) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            el[i].disabled = false;

            enableElements(el[i].children);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

How about achieving this using only HTML attribute 'disabled'

```
<form>
 <fieldset disabled>
  <div class="row">
   <input type="text" placeholder="">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <select></select>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <button class="button-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Just by putting disabled in the fieldset all the fields inside of that fieldset get disabled.

```
$('fieldset').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: you can just `disabled` the form

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the function below at various points.  Works in a div or button elements in a table as long as the right selector is used. Just ":button" would not re-enable for me.

```
function ToggleMenuButtons(bActivate) {
    if (bActivate == true) {
        $("#SelectorId :input[type='button']").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#SelectorId :input[type='button']").removeProp("disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: two in one solution great.

Answer (score 1):

For me the accepted answer did not work as I had some asp net hidden fields which got disabled as well so I chose only to disable visible fields

```
//just to save the list so we can enable fields later
var list = [];
$('#parent-selector').find(':input:visible:not([readonly][disabled]),button').each(function () {
    list.push('#' + this.id);
});

$(list.join(',')).attr('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will disable all the input but will not able it to btn class and also added class to overwrite disable css.

```
$('#EditForm :input').not('.btn').attr("disabled", true).addClass('disabledClass');
```

css class

```
.disabledClass{
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 228) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS Class to prevent from Editing the Div Elements

**CSS:**

```css
.divoverlay
{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:transparent;
z-index:1;
top:0;
}
```

**JS:**

```js
$('#divName').append('<div class=divoverlay></div>');
```

Or add the class name in HTML Tag.
It will prevent from editing the Div Elements.

Answer (score 0):

Only text type

```
$(".form-edit-account :input[type=text]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Only Password type

```
$(".form-edit-account :input[type=password]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Only Email Type

```
$(".form-edit-account :input[type=email]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your form inside `div` simply contains form inputting elements, then this simple query will **disable** every element inside `form` tag:

```
<div id="myForm">
    <form action="">
    ...
    </form>
</div>
```

However, it will also **disable** other than inputting elements in `form`, as it's effects will only be seen on input type elements, therefore suitable majorly for every type of forms!

```
$('#myForm *').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: Please fix your second sentence. It seems to say that your code will disable non-input elements, but then it says it will only affect input elements. Please clarify your meaning. *(Neat trick, by the way - good answer)*