# Nested Form to disable text field with selection box HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have code form.html and entry.php

First I want to disable textfield with selection box using javascript, then submit it to give an output.
If i not using this code `<form name="form1" method="post" action="entry.php">` form.html is success to display in web browser, but how i can submit it with one submit button?

form.html

```
<html>
<head> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.group').hide(); 
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#chooseForm').change(function() {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })  

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="entry.php">

    <select id="chooseForm" name="select">
        <option value="option1">Form1</option>
        <option value="option2">Form2</option>
        <option value="option3">Form3</option>
    </select>

    <form id="option1" class="group">
        <input name="a" value="form A"><br>
    </form>

    <form id="option2" class="group">
        <input name="a" value="form A"><br>
        <input name="b" value="form B"><br>
    </form>

    <form id="option3" class="group">
        <input name="a" value="form A"><br>
        <input name="b" value="form B"><br>
        <input name="c" value="form C"><br>
    </form>
<input value="Save" name="submit" type="submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

entry.php

```
<?php
$select = $_POST['select'];
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];

echo $select;
echo "<br>";
echo $a;
echo "<br>";
echo $b;
echo "<br>";
echo $c;
?>
```

Can anyone solve this code without nested form? thanks :)

Comment: can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [you can't nest forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms).
As I understand the idea is to group some elements. If so, then replace the interior `<form>`tags with `<div>`s.

The other problem is that you want to use the same input elements names through different sections. Basically, if `name` is not unique, it will get updated with the last occurrence's value. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="val 1" />
<input type="text" name="a" value="val 2" />
```

When the above is posted, `$_POST['a']` will contain `val 2` value. Even, if the second text-box is hidden. So either you make text-boxes names unique or you disable the ones, which are hidden. `disabled` attribute will make the control disabled for user input and also not present in `$_POST` array. So, in this case:

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="val 1" />
<input type="text" name="a" value="val 2" disabled />
```

`$_POST['a']` will contain `val 1` value, because the second text-box is disabled.
In your case, every time you hide a section you should disable all controls within the group. Here's how to do it: [disable all form elements inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290525/disable-all-form-elements-inside-div).