# How to disable form (user cannot checked, fill text , select dropdown etc.) in this form when process requests post ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

How to disable form (user cannot checked, fill text , select drop down etc.) in this form when process requests post ajax ?

i want to disable form `id="f1"` when process send post ajax , How can i do that ?

```
<script>
function send_requests_data(){
    $('#demoajax').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#f1').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
            $('#demoajax').show();
            $('#demoajax').html(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
}
// on load page call function code //
$(document).ready(send_requests_data());
</script>
```

Comment: What have tried to do?

Answer (score 3):

A possible answer may be found here:
[disable all form elements inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290525/disable-all-form-elements-inside-div)

TL;DR
try adding this:

```
$("#parent-selector :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

to the ajax call where parent-selector is either the div or form id.

Comment: This should use the `.prop()` method instead of the `.attr()` method.  But, I like this suggestion overall better than mine. It's simpler.

Comment: Good point. I will have to remember that the next time I use one of these. Never too late to do it a different way.

Comment: when success post requests `$("#parent-selector :input").attr("disabled", fault);` ?

Comment: @takemoerยังยังนา   `.prop('disabled',true);` before ajax and `.prop('disabled', false);` after success. Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope it helps :

```
function send_requests_data(){
    $('#id1 input,select').attr('disabled','disbaled');
    $('#demoajax').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#f1').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
            $('#demoajax').show();
            $('#demoajax').html(data);
            $('#id1 input,select').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('input, select ,textarea', '#f1'),function(){
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: `$.each` is really for arrays. You could just say `$('input, select ,textarea', '#f1').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can call the below function before calling your ajax function. It will disable all your form controls

```
     function disable() {
     var limit = document.forms[0].elements.length;
     for (i=0;i<limit;i++) {
     document.forms[0].elements[i].disabled = true;
        }
     }
```