# Jquery prop disabled value is not seen on server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, prop

I am setting and disabling the textbox using jquery. When I click on save and posted to server, I can't see this particular element value.

```
$('#FirstName').prop('disabled', true);
```

How can I disable the textbox and post the value to server?

Comment: do you use textboxfor for your textbox?  if you do then I would recommend using hiddenfor also.  that will ensure the value gets returned

Comment: I use textboxfor but I don't want to use hiddenfor because I have lot of controls which I need to disable them.

Comment: Disabled controls do not post back. You could make them readonly instead

Answer (score 1):

By design disabled form controls are not included in the submitted data. If your aim is to prevent users from changing the set value use `readonly` instead:

```
$('#FirstName').prop('readOnly', true);
```

To make all form fields within a given `div`, use the following:

```
$('div :input').prop( 'readOnly', true );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how to make all the elements(textbox,radio button, dropdown) inside div readonly?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use something what Trevor [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5290627/769678)

```
$('.container').find('input, textarea, button, select').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/kq8t0L6r/) works fine with `Chrome/Mozilla/IE 10,9,8`