# Enable & Disable a Div and its elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I am looking for a method to *Enable and Disable* the 
                                         **div id="dcalc"** and Its children.

```
<div id="dcalc" class="nerkheArz"
 style="left: 50px; top: 150px; width: 380px; height: 370px;
 background: #CDF; text-align: center" >
 <div class="nerkh-Arz"></div>
 <div id="calc"> </div>
</div>
```

I want to Disable them at loading the page and then by a click i can enable them ?

This is what i have tried

```
document.getElementById("dcalc").disabled = true;
```

Comment: What is the difference between an "enabled" and "disabled" `div` element? It is really just `input` elements that can be disabled. Or do you want to disable all child `input` elements within a `div`?

Comment: I want to disable every divs that are under main one

Comment: Please visit:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content/14973111#14973111

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You should be able to set these via the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) functions in jQuery as shown below:

**jQuery (< 1.7):**

```
// This will disable just the div
$("#dcacl").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

*or*

```
// This will disable everything contained in the div
$("#dcacl").children().attr("disabled","disabled");
```

**jQuery (>= 1.7):**

```
// This will disable just the div
$("#dcacl").prop('disabled',true);
```

*or*

```
// This will disable everything contained in the div
$("#dcacl").children().prop('disabled',true);
```

*or*

```
//  disable ALL descendants of the DIV
$("#dcacl *").prop('disabled',true);
```

**Javascript:**

```
// This will disable just the div
document.getElementById("dcalc").disabled = true;
```

*or*

```
// This will disable all the children of the div
var nodes = document.getElementById("dcalc").getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
     nodes[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: `.prop('disabled', true)` would be better. And your last code block leaks a global (you need `var i`).

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Thanks :) The post has been updated to fix the global variable issue, and now address both .attr() and .prop() solutions.

Comment: Thanks for very nice answer, Which one do you think is better and faster? shall I use JavaScript or Jquery !?

Comment: If you are already using JQuery - then I recommend using it. However, if you aren't the Javascript solution will be much easier to implement. As you will just have to wrap those in a <script> block. (These kinds of things are what jQuery really excels at)

Comment: 'code'<script >
//$("#dcalc").children(this).attr(disabled,"disabled");
//$("#dcalc").attr('disabled',true);
</script>'

Comment: If you want to use just the javascript suggestion you will need the following : <script type='text/javascript>var nodes = document.getElementById("dcalc").getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
     nodes[i].disabled = true;
}</script>

Comment: well I check the Jquery on and It doesnt work ?! Shall I bind it to load page or ?  this is my code shape :<srcipt>$("#dcalc").children(this).attr(disabled,"disabled");
$("#dcalc").attr('disabled',true);  </script> <body> <div id='1'> <div id="2"></div> </div></body>

Comment: by id="1" i meant dcalc . I checked the JS but it was not working too ??? can you tell me what exactly it should be shaped ?

Comment: how to bind the changes to the Div ?!

Comment: It doesn't work. I still can click the children links.

Comment: Me too, it doesn't work. I still can click the children links

Comment: NOTE that `$el.children()` only traverses a single level down the DOM, so it will NOT in fact disable ALL descendants of the DIV. So, @Emerald214 @oliver-pons, to accomplish this, you'd have to do something like `$("#dcac1 *").prop("disabled", true);` Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: What does `disabled=true` mean on a `div` in the DOM? What does it change? I've found a bug where a div has a KnockoutJs `enable` binding and once disabled, it seems to never re-enable. Trying to understand why disabling a div is even a thing.

Answer (score 56):

If you want to disable all the div's controls, you can try adding a transparent div on the div to disable, you gonna make it unclickable, also use fadeTo to create a disable appearance.

try this.

```
$('#DisableDiv').fadeTo('slow',.6);
$('#DisableDiv').append('<div style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:2;opacity:0.4;filter: alpha(opacity = 50)"></div>');
```

Comment: Combine it with suppressing keyboard and copy/paste events:
`var stopPropFn = function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
};

$('#DisableDiv').bind("keydown", stopPropFn);
$('#DisableDiv').bind("keypress", stopPropFn);
$('#DisableDiv').bind("paste", stopPropFn);`

Comment: This doesn't prevent the user going to the links or inputs with the "tab" key where they can still interact with them.

Comment: You should give the masking division an ID so you can delete it when you want to re-enable the division

Comment: How do you undo it ? I want this to be like a toggle.

Comment: @oliver give the div thats being appended an id such as "overlay". Then when you want to remove simply use $("#overlay").remove();

Answer (score 23):

The following selects all descendant elements and disables them:

```
$("#dcacl").find("*").prop("disabled", true);
```

But it only really makes sense to disable certain element types: inputs, buttons, etc., so you want a more specific selector:

```
$("#dcac1").find(":input").prop("disabled",true);
// noting that ":input" gives you the equivalent of
$("#dcac1").find("input,select,textarea,button").prop("disabled",true);
```

To re-enable you just set "disabled" to false.

> I want to Disable them at loading the page and then by a click i can enable them

OK, so put the above code in a document ready handler, and setup an appropriate click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dcac1kids = $("#dcac1").find(":input");
    $dcac1kids.prop("disabled",true);

    // not sure what you want to click on to re-enable
    $("selector for whatever you want to click").one("click",function() {
       $dcac1kids.prop("disabled",false);
    }
}
```

I've cached the results of the selector on the assumption that you're not adding more elements to the div between the page load and the click. And I've attached the click handler with [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) since you haven't specified a requirement to re-disable the elements so presumably the event only needs to be handled once. Of course you can change the `.one()` to `.click()` if appropriate.

Comment: I want to have it on page load ? can it be jquery ?

Comment: The last block of code in my answer does it on page load (well, on document ready which is a better choice for this) and it does it with jQuery - isn't that what you want?

Comment: It is not working ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468761/disable-div-on-load-is-not-working-why/8468858#8468858

Comment: Interesting... your answer does work while using `children()` won't work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8423836/114029 Why? I do see in Chrome Dev Tools that it correctly selects the children elements but they won't be disabled at all.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi - I don't know without seeing your html or perhaps a demo if you create one at jsfiddle.net. But in a general sense `.children()` only selects immediate children, which is why my answer uses `.find()` to get all matching descendent elements. You need to select form elements, it doesn't really make sense to disable divs.

Comment: Nice work thank you