# How to disable input/click on textbox/image using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to disable input event in textbox and click event on image in JavaScript.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    Img1: <img id="img1" onclick="alert('Clicked Div1');" />
</div>

<div id="div2">
    txt1: <input type="text" id="txt1" />
</div>

<input type="button" value="Disable It"  onclick="disable();" />
<input type="button" value="Enable It"  onclick="enable();" />
```

This is JavaScript:

```
function disable()
{
    document.getElementsByName('txt1').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("div1").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("div2").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("img1").disabled = true;
}
function enable()
{
    document.getElementsByName('txt1').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("div1").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("div2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("img1").disabled = false;
}
```

In the above code only image is disabled by `document.getElementById("img1").disabled = true;` that too only on IE8. It doesn't work on Chrome (V 32.0.1700.107 m) and Firefox (26.0).

I tried the JavaScript given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423836/1369235). But it doesn't work on Chrome and Firefox.

How can I do this? Am I missing anything? I am trying to achieve this using JavaScript (not [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/639815/1369235)).

Comment: @NikhilButani: I am trying with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target the text input by its id too.

```
document.getElementById('txt1').disabled = true;
```

Concerning the image, this might guide you in the right direction.
What you can do is add a function to `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` to the image element that prevents the left-click feature. [Here's a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qt22z/19/).

This won't disable the div's however.

```
function right(e) {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && e.which == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && event.button == 1) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}


function disableit() {
    document.getElementById('txt1').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("div1").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("div2").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("img1").onmouseup = right;
    document.getElementById("img1").onmousedown = right;
    document.getElementById("img1").onclick = right;
}

function enableit() {
    document.getElementById('txt1').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("div1").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("div2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("img1").onmouseup = null;
    document.getElementById("img1").onmousedown = null;
    document.getElementById("img1").onclick = yourFunction;
}

function yourFunction() {
    alert('Clicked Div1');
}
```

You should also set the `onclick` on the image to `yourFunction`, like this:

```
<img id="img1" onclick="yourFunction();" />
```

Comment: Sorry I misread `txt1` as `img1`. Is there any solution for image?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getElementById` for textbox.

Try like this:

```
function disable()
{
    document.getElementById('txt1').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById("div1").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("div2").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("img1").disabled = true;

}
function enable()
{
    document.getElementById('txt1').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById("div1").disabled = false;
   document.getElementById("div2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("img1").disabled = false;
}
```

Please Find working code here [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/qakeb/1/)

Comment: Thanks using `getElementById` it disables input in textbox and works on Chrome and FF too. Still looking for disabling click event on image.