# How to disable and enable a image?

Tags: javascript

I would like to disable and enable a div (inside a div i have two text box) on a single button click and i would like change the button name also like "if i click disable button it should disable the text box and disable name should become enable and vise verso".can some one help?.

```
function san() {
    san1(document.getElementById("div1"));
}

function san1(el) {
    try {
        el.disabled = el.disabled ? false : true;
    } catch (E) {}
    if (el.childNodes && el.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < el.childNodes.length; x++) {
            san1(el.childNodes[x]);

        }
    }
}
```

Html Code

```
<div id="div1">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td >
            <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" class="MyTestClass"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hypCalenStart" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ico-cal.gif"></asp:HyperLink>
            <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="StartDatePicker" runat="server" PopupButtonID="hypCalenStart"
               TargetControlID="txtStartDate" SelectedDate='<%# Datetime.Today() %>' Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
            </ajax:CalendarExtender>
         </td>
         <td >
            <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date"></asp:Label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" class="MyTestClass" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hypCalenEnd" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/ico-cal.gif"></asp:HyperLink>
            <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="EndDatePicker"  runat="server" PopupButtonID="hypCalenEnd"
               TargetControlID="txtEndDate" SelectedDate="<%# Datetime.Today() %>" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
            </ajax:CalendarExtender>
         </td>
         <td colspan=2 align="center">
            <asp:Button ID="cycloneenable"  OnClientClick="validate(1);" runat="server" Text="Enable" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Disable" onclick= "san()"/>
```

i have two textbox with calendars.the problem is even after disable i am able to select the date from the calender

Comment: Share what you've tried (code, any output/errors, unexpected behaviour), and what you've searched for!

Comment: @Luke:i have given code pls do see

Comment: Okay, so the logic is, recursively disable all children? What are the children (show HTML)? What happens if you remove the try-catch so as to not suppress errors?

Comment: @Luke:i have added the html

Comment: @saranya [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423812/enable-disable-a-div-and-its-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: Divs don't have a `disabled` attribute. You will need to disable the inputs.

Comment: @Bergi :yes...the problem for me is I have a popup calendar on calendar image click it will place the date in the text box .i can disable the text box .but the calendar is still enabled and if i select the date from calendar it places the date in disabled text box.

Comment: @saranya: Then make your image click handler respect the disabled property

Answer (score 2):

@saranya
The disabled attribute is not part of  the W3C spec for [div element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html), only for [form elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled).

Well if you want to enabled disabled the div, one should enabled disabled the
all control elements withing that div.
I have achieved using following way using **JavaScript**.

HTMl

```
<input type="button" value="Disable" id="enable-disable""/>

     <div class="two-text-box-div" >    
        inside a div i have two text box
        <input type="text" name"one" class="enable-disable-textbox">
        <input type="text" name"two" class="enable-disable-textbox">
     </div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function(){ 
            var btnEnableDisable = document.getElementById('enable-disable');
            var divTwoTextBoxDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('enable-disable-textbox');
            btnEnableDisable.onclick = function(){

                if(btnEnableDisable.value=='Disable'){
                    btnEnableDisable.value = 'Enable';
                    enbaleDisableDiv(true)

                }else{
                    btnEnableDisable.value = 'Disable';
                    enbaleDisableDiv(false)
                }
            }

            var enbaleDisableDiv = function(boolVal){
                for (var key in divTwoTextBoxDiv) {
                        divTwoTextBoxDiv[key].disabled = boolVal;
                    }
            } 
    }
```

Comment: :I have a popup calendar on calendar image click it will place the date in the text box .the code you have given disables the textbox.but  the calendar is still enabled and if i select the date from calendar it places the date in disabled textbox.

Comment: @saranya there is  no disabled attribute associated with image. please check here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp .            you have to hide that calendar so it not visible to end user on disable activity and show it again on enable activity.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button id="myButton" onclick="handleOnClick()">Disable</button>
```

JS

```
function handleOnClick() {
    var input = document.getElementById('myInput'),
        button = document.getElementById('myButton');
    input.disabled = !input.disabled;
    button.innerHTML = input.disabled ? "Enable" : "Disable";
}
```