# how to disable other buttons on the page while click on the first button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to disable Save button when I click Upload Button. on the Upload button I am getting data from Excel sheet and storing it into Gridview, so it takes time, I want to prevent user to click Save button at that period of time.
I am using ASP.Net Web Forms Technology.
Following Code is the Upload Button Code.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload"OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Please Wait';" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Comment: You can use JavaScript for this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423812/enable-disable-a-div-and-its-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: Can't you just disable it in your `btnUpload_Click` event? I.e.: `btnSave.Enabled = false;`. When your upload is finished you just need to re-enable it.

Comment: I have tried but its not working.