# disable a div block of bootstrap 5 spinner using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I want to disable a div block of spinner.

HTML:

```
    <div class="spinner-grow" role="status" id="buspinner" style="width: 20px; height:20px; margin-top: 5px">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var spinElement = document.getElementById("buspinner"); 
spinElement.disabled = true
```

I followed below answer and used above steps, but it's not working. What am I missing here?
[Enable & Disable a Div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423836/2490398)

Comment: Div elements don't have a disabled property. Is this a Bootstrap component property? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have used select2 library for multiselect dropdown, so as a feature to add spinner inside select field, it's an alternative to add an spinner outside the select field.

Comment: If you see, the answer also includes that "*This will disable just the div*"

Comment: If you look a little deeper you'll find it mentioned that you can only disable certain element types, such as inputs.