# How can I prevent div from shaking when I click fast?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slide

My code is:

```js
$(function() {
  const fullSection = $(".fullsection");
  const container = $("#container");

  // closed fullSection => height:0%();
  $(".fullsection").each(function(index, item) {
    if (!$(item).hasClass("active")) {
      $(item).animate({
        height: "0%",
      });
    }
  });

  // opened fullSection => height:100%();
  var i = 500;
  $(".fullsection").each(function(index, item) {
    if (!$(item).hasClass("active")) {
      $(item).animate({
        height: "100%",
      }, i);
      //console.log(item);
      //console.log(i);
      i += 150;
    }
    // console.log(fullSectionInactive);
  });

  var sum = 0;
  $(fullSection).click(function(event) {
    var functionCompleted = false;
    var chosenWidth = $(this).css("width");
    var chosenWidthNum = parseInt($(this).css("width"));
    var widthactive = parseInt($(this).siblings(".active").css("width"));
    var widthInactive = parseInt(!$(this).siblings(".active").css("width"));
    // Check if there are any opened section
    // if so, closing.
    $(this).siblings().each(function(index, item) {
      var eachWidthNum = parseInt($(this).css("width"));
      if (Math.floor(eachWidthNum) == Math.floor(widthactive)) {
        $(item).removeClass("active");
      }
    });
    // and the clicked element expands
    // if(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    // }
  });
});
```

```css
/* reset */

@import url("reset.css");

/* font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive; */


/* 400 only */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&display=swap');

/* global class */

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.fullsection {
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px, 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  /* opacity: 0; */
}

.active {
  width: 85%;
}

.section_1 {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.section_2 {
  background-color: teal;
}

.section_3 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.section_4 {
  background-color: slateblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="fullsection section_1 active"></div>
  <div class="fullsection section_2"></div>
  <div class="fullsection section_3"></div>
  <div class="fullsection section_4"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

i am making a page with only js (jquery) and faced a challenge.
its works fine when I click each div (`.fullSection`) in slow tempo. However once I click each div with relatively fast tempo, suddenly divs (mainly fourth one) jerks and shakes.

I add/remove class name in order to change the width, instead of using `animate();` (don't know why but it jerks pretty hard)

I want to prevent users from clicking while the div is still in changing width.
or whatever that could stop those divs from jerking and shaking..

I have tried `is.("animating")` using `return false`

I want to prevent users from clicking while the div is still in changing width.
or whatever that could stop those divs from jerking and shaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ontransitionend`, you can detect when an animation has finished and work with states to allow a new animation to take place.
Maybe this solves it for you.

```
$(this).on('transitionend', function(){
    isAnimating = true
 });
```

```js
$(function() {
    const fullSection = $(".fullsection"),
        container = $("#container"),
        timingStep = 150;
    
    // use state
    let canWeAnimate = true;

    fullSection.not(".active").animate({ height: "0%" });

    fullSection.each(function(index, item) {
        if (!$(item).hasClass("active")) {
            $(item).animate({ height: "100%" }, index * timingStep + 500);
        }
    });

    fullSection.click(function() {
        // check if we can animate
        if (!canWeAnimate || $(this).hasClass("active")) return;

        const _this = $(this);
        // set state to false to prevent animations
        canWeAnimate = false;

        _this.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
        _this.addClass("active");

        _this.on("transitionend", () => {
            // set state to true to allow animations again
            canWeAnimate = true;
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/* reset */

@import url("reset.css");

/* font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive; */


/* 400 only */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&display=swap');

/* global class */

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.fullsection {
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px, 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  /* opacity: 0; */
}

.active {
  width: 85%;
}

.section_1 {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.section_2 {
  background-color: teal;
}

.section_3 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.section_4 {
  background-color: slateblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="fullsection section_1 active"></div>
  <div class="fullsection section_2"></div>
  <div class="fullsection section_3"></div>
  <div class="fullsection section_4"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423812/enable-disable-a-div-and-its-elements-in-javascript) the button or div on its click event before animation and enable it after the animation completes. You can use an animate [callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to enable the button or div.

```
$( "#clickme)" ).on( "click", function() {
   // disable button here
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // enable button. it invoke on animation completion 
  });
});
```