# Only visible DIV

Tags: jquery, css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable all div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content)

Is it possible to only show div but you can not click on anything which is in? Like "blocked" div? Cause I have buttons, selects, and some information in this div, so I want only to make it visible but not working.

Comment: duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content

Answer (score 3):

You may add a transparent div over the whole window.

```
$('body').append($('<div style="opacity:0; z-index:10; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0">'));
```

Fiddle demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/HeNwE/

Comment: Having seemingly active yet unclickable elements on a web page is confusing to the user and bad design.

Comment: @Endy This is an answer to the question. I see a good use case : when you add a dialog over everything (when I do it I use a grey not totally transparent div to make it more clear).

Comment: Look at the answer posted in the comment on the question and then decide which approach you think is better.

Answer (score 0):

Lokase has the right idea.

```
$(".wrapper-div-class").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

You could also try to have a 100% x 100% div z-indexed on top of the div that contains all of the elements.

Test out Endy's answer for handeling input elements on the page.

Comment: You can still access the inputs with keyboard.

Comment: so if I have <div id="zakladne_info"> script will looks like `<script>
 $("#zakladne_info").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>` ?

Comment: Correct. And you don't need it, but always good practice to include the closing ; after your function method. <script> $('#zakladny_popis_p').on('click', function(event){ event.preventDefault(); }); </script>

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent div into your target div, over the whole content.
Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/TkTx6/2/

html :

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <button></button>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    width : 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;        
}
div div {
    background : transparent;
    cursor: default;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can simply place an absolutely positioned div that is the same size as your container over top of your content. This will disallow interactivity with the elements below.

```
<style type="text/css">
#container{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    }

#shield{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    }
```

```
<div id="container">
<div id="shield"></div>
<a href="#" title="">You can't click me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
<div onclick="return false">
... <!-- insert here your buttons -->
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work : the div isn't the first receiver of the event.

Comment: sorry but if you use jquery, you could try this http://jsfiddle.net/8mCYv/3/

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent layer over the div: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/xXhnc/).

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}​
```

Answer (score -1):

Use preventDefault on any element you want to override:

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

You can also use stopPropagation in specific instances as well

[event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: You would have to bind a lot of events, as you can still use inputs with your keyboard.

Answer (score -3):

You could make all the input elements disabled on the div with Javascript and JQuery, then enable them when you choose to.

Example:

```
$('.myDiv:input').each(function()) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

IF you don't need to dynamically change the inputs then just set 'disabled="disabled"' into the elements.

This approach is also better than the "invisible div" as it can be very confusing to a user if he/she can't click on a control on a page, or select text.

Comment: Does this handle any link elements on the page?

Comment: Whomever voted this down can explain why.

Comment: There is no mention of links. Also, having unclickable links on a page is very bad design.

Comment: The entire concept of having an unusable form is bad design, but that is what the question poses.

Comment: Look at the answer posted in the comment on the question and then decide which approach you think is better.

Comment: Funny how this is the correct answer on another duplicated, completely identical case, yet here it is downvoted to nothing. Guess people favor bad approaches and bad web design over good user experiences.

Comment: I guess someone didn't like this question and downvoted all of the answers.