# How to Disable whole Div Contents without using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

As I have Basic knowledge of JavaScript I want to do operation like following :

- By using Two radio button giving two option for Payment :

  1. By Cash
  2. By Check
- If user select the radio button of Cash the Cheque Button should also disable and the  Div of Cheque  in which the details like cheque no and bank name is should also disable.
- And visa Versa

Is there a way to do that without using JQuery? (disable a div and get all content disabled also)

Thanks in Advance For Help.

Comment: Could you post some of your HTML and what you have tried?

Comment: If you can do something with jQuery, you can also do it with vanilla JavaScript because (all together now) jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Please show what you've tried so far...

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content

Comment: Absolutely possible to write the functionality what you want in javascript without using jquery.

Comment: @javapirate:He has used the JQuery to Solve. Not Duplication

Comment: iterate all the form elements inside the div tag and then disable them. Try this and let us know the result

Comment: @javapirate:I think It will Work

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("myDivId").disabled = true;
```

To disable all elements inside the div, try this:

```
var allChildNodes = document.getElementById("myDivId").getElementsByTagName('*');

for(var i = 0; i < allChildNodes.length; i++)
{
   allChildNodes[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: :Can You Make it more simpler ?

Answer (score 1):

This code will disable all elements within the given container.

```
var container = document.getElementById("cashContainer");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input").concat(document.getElementsByTagName("select"));
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Applying the same code you can re-enable the other container.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="cashcheck" value="cash" checked />Cash<br />
<div id="cash">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="cashTxt1" />
        <input type="text" name="cashTxt2" />
    </form>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="cashcheck" value="check" />Check<br />
<div id="check">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="checkTxt1" disabled />
        <input type="text" name="checkTxt2" disabled />
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload=function(){
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('cashcheck');
    radios[0].onchange=toggle;
    radios[1].onchange=toggle;
};

function toggle()
{
    if(this.checked)
    {
        var div = document.getElementById(this.value),
        inputs = div.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].getElementsByTagName('*');
        for( var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
        {
            inputs[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
        }

        var op = this.value == 'cash' ? 'check' : 'cash',
        divOp = document.getElementById(op),
        divOpInputs = divOp.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].getElementsByTagName('*');
        for( var i=0; i<divOpInputs.length; i++)
        {
            divOpInputs[i].setAttribute('disabled');
        }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TjAZq/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<fieldset disabled="true">
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <br>

  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <br>

  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <br>
</fieldset>
```