# how to disable DIV element and everything inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to disable a DIV and all it's content using Javascript.  I can swear that doing a simple

```
<div disabled="true">
```

was working for me before, but for some reason it no longer works.  I don't understand why.

In IE10: the text "Click Me" is not greyed out and click handler still works.

I actually need this working for IE10.  Below is my code.

```
<html>
    <script>
         function disableTest(){

            document.getElementById("test").disabled = true;
            var nodes = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName('*');
            for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
                nodes[i].disabled = true;
            }

         }


     </script>

<body onload="disableTest();">
   <div id="test">
       <div onclick="alert('hello');">
           Click Me
       </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm just trying to disable everything inside a DIV and it's handlers.

Comment: Nope! Divs can't be disabled. Only form and form elems.

Comment: `"true"` is not a valid value for the `disabled`-attribute (in the markup)

Comment: Actually in Quirks-mode IE can disable a `div`, but it only grays button texts, it doesn't prevent events firing.

Comment: and advice, use `data-dissabled` for this kind of stuff in elements that are not forms

Comment: Bergi is right. It should look like `<input type=text disabled />`.

Comment: You can define custom attributes in xHTML and achieve disable with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content/65563261#65563261

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this!

```
$("#test *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
```

I don't see you using jquery above, but you have it listed as a tag.

Comment: `disabled` isn't a valid property for `div`.

Comment: `.prop("disabled", true)` would be better (if it would work at all)

Comment: This sets all the children of the div to disabled.  So if he/she has inputs or radio buttons, it will disable them.  Getting more specific with the selectors is highly recommended.

Comment: I tried both .attr("disabled", "disabled") and .prop("disabled", true) but they only disable the onclick handler.  The text is NOT greyed out.

Comment: Ah, you should specify that in your original post.  Make a `.disabled` class in your css that sets `color: grey;`  and maybe `background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .2);` and add the class `$("#test").addClass("disabled");`

Comment: yeah this is part of bigger webapp using jQuery, just wanted to make problem simple. Thanks this works for me. I'm sure this was working in IE9, but just got new IE10 update.

Comment: @Danwilliger ;its is working...but what to do if I again want to enable it.,.?

Comment: @Hardik, Try: $("#test").prop("disabled", false); or $("#test").removeAttr("disabled");

Comment: @MaxStrater It won't switch the old click bindings on

Comment: It the most unefficient way to do this... What if page has many elements? Better way to go is: `$('#test').find('*')` or better specify `input` instead of `*`

Comment: and how to enable again?

Comment: `for (let x of temp0.querySelectorAll('*')) { x.disabled = true; }`

Comment: To enable: $("#test *").attr("disabled", false).off('click');

Answer (score 466):

The following css statement disables click events

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Comment: Really good one, but there are some that today doesn't suport it: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: This one is really good for select2 disabling as the built-in feture for that doesn't really work.

Comment: +10, StackOverflow never lets me down. Nevermind about the obsolete IE users, I warn them to upgrade their browser always.

Comment: Lol I wish the real world was as simple as "Nevermind about the obsolete IE users". Sadly I still have to support IE10 since public service department are slow at updating *Sigh* So I can't use what would have been perfect: pointer-events :'-(

Comment: Unfortunately you can still navigate in between elements with Tab key (and once you navigated to an element, you can edit it as well).

Comment: The standard `disabled` attribute on form fields addresses all forms of input, not just the mouse. This only addresses disabling mouse input.

Comment: As @RoyTinker said, this does not affect form elements. With whatever logic you're adding the `pointer-events: none` to your div, also have all form elements within that "disabled"-looking div to have the `disabled=true` attribute as well.

Comment: @AndrewE note the `disabled` attribute doesn't have to have a value in HTML 4-5 (i.e. `<input [...] disabled>` is fine). However, if your document is XHTML (or you're using a library that requires a value), the correct value to use is `disabled` (i.e. `<input [...] disabled="disabled">`).

Answer (score 18):

javascript and jQuery

```js
function sah() {
        $("#div2").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
        var x1=$("#div2").hasClass("disabledDiv");
        
        (x1==true)?$("#div2").removeClass("disabledDiv"):$("#div2").addClass("disabledDiv");
  sah1(document.getElementById("div1"));

}

    function sah1(el) {
        try {
            el.disabled = el.disabled ? false : true;
        } catch (E) {}
        if (el.childNodes && el.childNodes.length > 0) {
            for (var x = 0; x < el.childNodes.length; x++) {
                sah1(el.childNodes[x]);
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
#div2{
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:#777;
  width:150px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.disabledDiv {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
        <div id="div2" onclick="alert('Hello')">Click me</div>
        <input type="text" value="SAH Computer" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="SAH Computer" />
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" />Male
        <Br />
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" />Female
        <Br />
    </div>
    <Br />
    <Br />
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="sah()" />
```

Comment: 'disabled' doesn't work on divs

Comment: Working fine for me in Chrome, Mozilla and IE. just checked. Will you copy paste above example and check it?

Comment: @MandeepJain, for your convenience I add code to snippet. Run above snippet.

Comment: Thanks for replying on this old post. But, only form and form elements can be disabled. Your code disables all the input elements but not the div itself.

Comment: @MandeepJain I think you want to disabled div click event right? check above code. Now whole div is disabled as per your requirement. Just update me its working for you or not.

Comment: Yes. But your original answer said pure javascript no jquery which was my requirement. Its ok. Thanks for the efforts. I have found another solution :)

Answer (score 11):

I think inline scripts are hard to stop instead you can try with this:

```
<div id="test">
    <div>Click Me</div>
</div>
```

and script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#test').children().click(function(){
      alert('hello');
    });
    $('#test').children().off('click');
});
```

#### [CHEKOUT FIDDLE AND SEE IT HELPS](http://jsfiddle.net/WS47f/)

[Read More about .off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "disable" to disable a click event. I don't know how or if it worked in IE6-9, but it didn't work on Chrome, and it shouldn't work on IE10 like that.

You can disable the onclick event, too, by attaching an event that cancels:

```
;(function () {
    function cancel () { return false; };
    document.getElementById("test").disabled = true;
    var nodes = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName('*');
    console.log(nodes);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].setAttribute('disabled', true);
        nodes[i].onclick = cancel;
    }
}());
```

Furthermore, setting "disabled" on a node directly doesn't necessarily add the attribute- using setAttribute does.

http://jsfiddle.net/2fPZu/