# How to disable google map using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a map like below

```
<div id="geolocation_div" style="cursor: pointer;">                    

                    <p:poll id="geolocationpoll" interval="10000" listener="#{geoFenceSettingsBean.init()}" update="mappy"/>
                    <p:gmap  id="mappy" center="#{geoFenceSettingsBean.latitude},#{geoFenceSettingsBean.longitude}"
                             streetView="true" zoom="#{geoFenceSettingsBean.zoom}" model="#{geoFenceSettingsBean.emptyModel}" 
                             type="ROADMAP" disableDefaultUI="true" onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);" style="width:1000px;height:500px;color: #005172;cursor:pointer;margin-top: 20px" >                    

                    </p:gmap>

                </div>
```

I want disable this div content

when i tried in my javascript function like below

```
document.getElementById('geolocation_div').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('geolocation_div').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

the above two line i am able to execute but, when i tried like

```
document.getElementById('geolocation_div').disabled = true;
```

the above line not working

I want to disable the map content.Can any one plz let me know where i did a mistake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555295/how-to-disable-div-element-and-everything-inside

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i tried like $("#geolocation_div *").attr("disabled", true).off('click'); still unable to disable the div content