# How to Style a disable DIV element

Tags: html, css

I can make an input element respond to `:hover` and `:hover:disable`

But looks like a div doesn't respond the same.

```css
.btn {
  width: 99px;
  border-color: 2px #787878;
  background-color: #CACACA;
  margin-left: 76px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 26px;
  -moz-border-radius: 26px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover:disabled {
  background: red;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn" id="divDisable" style=" height: 30px;line-height: 30px; text-align: center;" disabled>Disabled
</div>

<input class="btn" id="iDisabled" type="submit" value="Disabled" disabled>
```

[Full Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/dropyghost/yhus8nsj/) with everything i tried

**Bonus Info**

Question was answer div doesn't have Disable

[Make div content Disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555295/how-to-disable-div-element-and-everything-inside)

http://jsfiddle.net/WS47f/

Comment: I don't think the div is meant to be "disabled", can't you add a "disabled" css class?

Comment: @sdcr My question is regarding div, not input.

Comment: @DavidRobinson How is my question duplicated? The duplicate suggestion is regarding an Input element, and as you can see in the accepted answer INPUT have DISABLED property but DIV doesnt. So you need a workaround for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A div element doesn't have a disable attribute. You could add a class in this case for your CSS.

```
div.divDisable:hover {}
```

Comment: I will try that, make sense if there isn't disable attribute. I rechange the Title again. The issue isnt disable the DIV. The issue was style a disable DIV.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late for the party, but solution is to use `.btn[disabled]:hover` instead of `.btn:disabled:hover`. First one does not detect disabled state (which doesn't exist on div) but rather targets existence of `disabled` attribute.

```css
.btn {
  width: 99px;
  border-color: 2px #787878;
  background-color: #CACACA;
  margin-left: 76px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 26px;
  -moz-border-radius: 26px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn[disabled]:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn" id="divDisable" style=" height: 30px;line-height: 30px; text-align: center;" disabled>Disabled
</div>

<input class="btn" id="iDisabled" type="submit" value="Disabled" disabled>
```

Answer (score -1):

To get both to do the same thing do:

```
    .btn:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

Here is a Fiddle that demonstrates: https://jsfiddle.net/cs8rbjkh/

Comment: I didnt downvote you. But i try your suggestion and didnt work. Maybe you can submit a fiddle code.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cs8rbjkh/ Between the accepted answer and mine, they accomplish the same thing, just a different way.