# How to totally disable a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which has some buttons and text inputs. I want to totally disable all the things inside this component until some other works are complete. How to make the entire inner component disabled?

Comment: Disabled? why not hidden ?

Comment: Why are you even showing it if that is the case?

Comment: I want to show it ..design requirements ..but just low opacity but the click should not work for that div

Answer (score 36):

You can add `disabled` props and use CSS to disable div

```
const MyComponent = ({disabled}) => {
    return (
        <div style={disabled ? {pointerEvents: "none", opacity: "0.4"} : {}}>
            <h1> Text</h1>
            <input type="text"/>
            <input type="password"/>
            <button>Login</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Who would've guessed that the answer is CSS? Thanks mate!

Comment: Where were you all this time.
It worked really well.
Spend hours to find perfect solutions for this.
Thanks a lot....

Comment: Would you be able to navigate via keyboard to the input field and enter stuff?

Comment: Not a great answer. User can still navigate to the controls via the keyboard, and use them.

Answer (score 11):

Better to use `form` and `fieldset`, and put all the input/button elements inside that. You can disable all of them by setting the property `disabled` to `fieldset`.

Refer [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) for more details.

Working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = { disable: false }
  }
  
  toggleDisable = () => this.setState(prevState => ({disable: !prevState.disable}))
  
  buttonClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('button clicked');
  }
  
  render (){
    return (
      <div>
        <button className='toggle' onClick={this.toggleDisable}>Toggle Disable</button>
        <form>
          <fieldset disabled={this.state.disable}>
            <input />
            <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>Button</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.toggle {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: Note that, even though the inputs are grey in IE11, you can still type in them (bug).

Comment: Much better answer than [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51260245/197591) currently with the highest votes. This one is true disabling that prevents keyboard interaction, also.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **disabled prop pattern** to save the day.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SomeComponent disabled />
    </div>
  );
};

const SomeComponent = ({ disabled = false }) => {
  return (
    !disabled && (
      <div>
        <h2>Disable SomeComponent to see magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    )
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add a `disabled` prop on the component and pass it on to the inner fields like

```
<MyComponent disabled={shouldComponentBeDisabled} {...otherProps} />
```

and in implementation

```
const MyComponent = ({disabled}) => {
    return <div>
          <button disabled={disabled}>someBtn</button>
          <input type="text" disabled={disabled}/>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: that way it would be too difficult ..i have lots of buttons and input..can that be done for the entire div being rendered in the child?

Comment: Unfortunately with React, the above is the best you can do, but the same thing can be done using jquery

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555295/how-to-disable-div-element-and-everything-inside However its not recommended to use jquery with react