# HTML - can focus elements under transparent div using tab key

Tags: html, css

I'm using transparent div with higher z-index to disable content on the page (for modal dialog, etc.). It works just fine, except that I recently discovered that you may tab to the elements behind transparent div using tab key, and push the buttons that have focus using Enter key, which isn't exactly what i want when disabling the content. Curious if there's a way to prevent that...

Comment: You aren't truly disabling content, just hiding it.  You should disable with javascript (or with a library like jQuery).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content.

Comment: Please post your code