# How to create a tab section in another tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

i want to run tabs within tabs. this is the first tab section which is running without problems.

```
<div id="tabs2" class="tabs">

    <ul>
        <li class="skew-25 active">
            <a class="skew25" href="#"> 1 tab</a>
        </li>
        <li class="skew-25"></li>
        <li class="skew-25"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-pane">
        <div class="tab-panel active" style="display: block;"> 1 tab output</div>
        <div class="tab-panel" style="display: none;">2 tab output</div>
        <div class="tab-panel" style="display: none;">3 tab output</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now I include another tab within the sections (called 'tab output') of the above:

```
<div id="tabs4" class="tabs tabs-vertical">

    <ul>
        <li class="skew-25 active">tab within tab section</li>
        <li class="skew-25">
            <a class="skew25" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="skew-25"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-pane">
        <div class="tab-panel active" style="display: block;">content</div>
        <div class="tab-panel" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="tab-panel" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

this second code i include in '1 tab output' '2 tab output' and '3 tab output'

Problem is they will ether not send output, not available to choose or not active when apply to a tab in first tab. How to fix this?

Javascripts are:

```
function(e) {
  if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ind = $(this).parent().index();
    tabsUl.find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    tabsPane.find('.tab-panel').fadeOut(0).removeClass('active');
    tabsPane.find('.tab-panel').eq(ind).fadeIn(350).addClass('active');
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and

```
f = v.handle = function(e) {
  return typeof x === i || e && x.event.triggered === e.type ? t : x.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem, arguments)
}
```

normal

```
/* ================ Tabs. ================ */
    $.fn.tabs = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            direction: ''
        };
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        if(options.direction == "vertical"){
            $(this).addClass('tabs-vertical');
        }
        var tabsUl = $(this).find(' > ul'),
            activeTab = tabsUl.find('li.active').index(),
            tabsPane = $(this).find('.tabs-pane');
        tabsPane.find('.tab-panel').fadeOut();
        tabsPane.find('.tab-panel').eq(activeTab).fadeIn();
        tabsUl.find('li').find('a').click(function(e){
            if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
                e.preventDefault();
                var ind = $(this).parent().index();
                tabsUl.find('li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                tabsPane.find('.tab-panel').fadeOut(0).removeClass('active');
                tabsPane.find('.tab-panel').eq(ind).fadeIn(350).addClass('active');
                return false;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the div and all its contents with jQuery like so:
[How to disable all div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content)

Also, instead of all that js code you can use [jQueryUI Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) or [Bootstrap tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp) (also [explained here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp) scroll down to the Toggable Tabs section at the bottom of the page).