# Disable Form Input with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following form element I need to disable from accessing via the mouse using purely CSS.  I do not have access to the form element to disable by editing the form input markeup, I only have access to the CSS style sheets.

```
<input type="text" name="rs:def:website" size="48" maxlength="64">
```

I'm attempting to use the `pointer-events:none` to disable the element from being able to accept input. I need to make sure I don't disable other text input.

This is what I've tried with no luck. Any suggestions?

```
.rs:def:website .input{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Why use `pointer-events` instead of the `disabled` or `readonly` attributes?

Comment: The dot notation is for class selector, but you try to address the element by an attribute different from `class`. Also, space in the selector means that the second part is the descendant of the first one, but you have a single element. Have you tried `input[name="rs:def:website"]` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable all div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content)

Comment: Keep in mind that you still be able to access the field with your `tab` key.

Comment: pointer event is not meant to disable the input it will just prevent from clicking the element, you can still focus the input by using the keyboard by pressing tab button and then you can input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct CSS selector:

```css
input[name="rs:def:website"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="rs:def:website" size="48" maxlength="64">
```

As noted by other answers, this is not a foolproof way to prevent users from editing this input.

Comment: You can still tab to it

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with pure CSS. `pointer-events: none;` might work in some cases, but you can still <kbd>Tab</kbd> through.

You will need to change the actual HTML. Add `disabled`, either directly in the HTML-file or via Javascript.

```
<input type="text" name="rs:def:website" size="48" maxlength="64" disabled>
```

Comment: Please note that disabled input won't be submitted.

Answer (score -2):

simply use `disabled` to disable input.

```html
<input type="submit" disabled>
```