# how to disable a single fieldset row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I can show and hide individual fieldset rows in jQuery 3.3.1, like this:

```
$("div.form-row.field-construction_start_date").show();
$("div.form-row.field-construction_start_date").hide();
```

But let's say I want to disable an individual fieldset row and all the controls in that singular row, like this:

```
$("div.form-row.field-construction_start_date").prop("disabled",true);
```

It does not work. Might anyone have some insight as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `div` element does not have a `disabled` attribute or property. You have to use a `fieldset` element, or disable individual controls within the `div`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable all div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div.form-row.field-construction_start_date :input").prop("disabled",true);
```