# Disable attribute on div will still fire a click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that has an icon in it, I add disabled property to the div and the click event still fires. So I went and created a copy of the div and changed the div to a button. Both have click events, yet the button won't fire when clicked on, but the div one will fire. Why is this, and how to I stop the click event firing when I click on the div?

I know that I can check for the disabled attribute during the click event, but wondering why I would have to do that and why the disabled doesn't work on a div

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  alert("clicked");
});

$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
#btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn[disabled] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

#btn1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn1[disabled] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="btn" class="disabled" disabled>
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</div>

<button id="btn1" class="fa fa-undo" disabled>
click
</button>
```

Comment: The answer is all here I'd say - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content  -- they do even mention that disabled is not defined for div elements in the w3c spec.

Comment: Disabled isn't a valid attribute for a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disabled attribute does not work on `div`.
If you insist on not checking for the attribute, you can use the `:not()` selector.

```
$('#btn:not(.disabled)').on('click', function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

`'#btn:not(.disabled)'` looks for elements with id `btn` and without a `disabled` class.

Answer (score 2):

`<div>` does not have `disabled` property, you have to check if it is disabled when clicking.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).prop("disabled"))
  alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: My friend the comment was 2 min ago my answer was 7 min ago

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the following css to disable click on div element as div element doesn't have disabled attribute:

```
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
```

Hope this helps..thanks