# I am navigating the html with arrow keys(up, down) focus was going to each div element. I want to skip the focus of one div element in the html page

Tags: html, jquery

```
<div class="first">First</div>
<div class="second">Second</div>
<div class="third">Third</div>
```

I am navigating the html with arrow keys(up, down) focus was going to each div element. I want to skip the focus of one div element in the html page

I tried with the below code

```
$('.second').onKeyDown= {e => {
if(e.key == "ArrowUp" || e.key == "ArrowDown") {
e.stopPropagation();
e.PreventDefault();
return false:
}
e.stopPropagation();
}}
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you elaborate more or provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that is what you want, but you can make elements unfocusable.
See here for refference: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

```
<div class="first">First</div>
<div class="second" tabIndex="-1">Secoond</div>
<div class="third">Third</div>
```

Note that an element with a negative tabindex is still focusable, it just cannot be reached using sequential focus navigation (i.e. tabbing)

Comment: If we have tabindex="-1" On tabbing it will unfocusable but while navigating through the arrow keys it is focusable. I want it to unfocusable while navigating through arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

from: [How to disable all div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content)

```
$("#mydiv").addClass("disabledbutton");
```

css

```
.disabledbutton {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```