# Serialize a Form but some Elements

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form which has elements in a couple of divs.

Based on a drop down, some of these divs might be hidden and some will be displayed.

i want to Serialize the form with just the element which are visible and not the hidden divs.

Is there any way I can filter out those hidden divs.

tried this but doesn't work

`$('<tr />').data($(this).find('form:not(.child:hidden)').serializeObject());`

serializeObject is a plugin which converts serializeArray into an Object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that in your context `this` is the `<form>` try the following:

```
var data = $(':input:visible', this).serialize();
$('<tr />').data(data);
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5UgpM/1/).

Comment: it can be textarea, select, checkbox, radio (basically I dont want to check for each and every visible element, i want to select all elements and negate the elements in hidden div)

Comment: Oops sorry. In this case put `:` in front of `input`, like this `:input:visible`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you `disable` the unused form elements, they do not get submitted with the form. That may be the easiest/quickest solution.

From a previous question on SO, I have these defined in my local extensions:

```
/* 
    Extension methods to quickly enable/disable form elements 
    @@see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625109/jquery-script-load-timing/625126#625126
*/
$.fn.disable = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (typeof this.disabled != "undefined") this.disabled = true;
    });
}

$.fn.enable = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (typeof this.disabled != "undefined") this.disabled = false;
    });
}
```

So, you could do something like:

```
$('.hidden-div-class').disable();
```

And then serialize the form.